# [SOLVED] Number of primitive shapes does not match number of poses in collision object message

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i would like to add a STL collision object. I have similar code and it works perfectly with primitive box.
I followed https://answers.ros.org/question/231148/insert-obstacles-in-moveit-with-motion-plannersc-api/
but it still writes me
`[ERROR] [1594897964.204647300]: Number of primitive shapes does not match number of poses in collision object message`
And i cannot see an *.STL file in RViz.
ROS Melodic, windows 10 - Ubuntu terminal, Xming.

Any adwices what i'm doing wrong? Thank you.
(Apologize for bad english).

```
uname -a
```

`Linux ### 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #836-Microsoft Mon May 05 16:04:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

float addMeshCollObj(float fX, float fY, float fZ, string sName){

```
    static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "arm";
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(PLANNING_GROUP);
    moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
    const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group =move_group.getCurrentState()>getJointModelGroup(PLANNING_GROUP);
    moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object;
    collision_object.header.frame_id = move_group.getPlanningFrame();
    collision_object.id = sName;
    Vector3d b(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
    shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://robot_rx160/meshes/gtbx/Ramecek.STL",b);

    shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;
    shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;  
    shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
    mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);

    collision_object.meshes.resize(1);
    collision_object.mesh_poses.resize(1);
    collision_object.meshes[0] = mesh;

    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.x= fX;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.y= fY;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].position.z= fZ;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w=0.0; 
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x=0.0; 
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y=0.0;
    collision_object.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z=0.0;   

    collision_object.meshes.push_back(mesh);
    collision_object.mesh_poses.push_back(collision_object.mesh_poses[0]);
    collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;

    std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;
    collision_objects.push_back(collision_object);
    ROS_INFO("Add an object \"%s\" into the world", sName.c_str());
    planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);

    sleep(1.0);
    return 0.0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357348/%5Bsolved%5D-number-of-primitive-shapes-does-not-match-number-of-poses-in-collision-object-message/) by [Quark](https://answers.ros.org/users/56673/quark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solve it.
The problem was in the vector. I removed at the end the `,b` from

`shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://robot_rx160/meshes/gtbx/Ramecek.STL",b);`

so

`shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://robot_rx160/meshes/gtbx/Ramecek.STL");`

and also removed the lines

```
collision_object.meshes.push_back(mesh);

collision_object.mesh_poses.push_back(collision_object.mesh_poses[0]);
```

And now it is OK.
Thank you for help.

---

Originally posted by [Quark](https://answers.ros.org/users/56673/quark/) with karma: 16 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0